# How to resolve unique keys required error when using <MemoryRouter /> in a test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jestjs

I'm writing snapshot tests for a React application, and I'm finding that when I write tests using `<MemoryRouter/>` in them, it throws a warning that I need to have a unique key prop.

When I looked at the react-router documentation, there was no mention of needing a key, and I haven't found a solution to this particular issue elsewhere.

This is what my test looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router'
import Navbar from '../Navbar';

it('renders a snapshot', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(
    <MemoryRouter  
      initialEntries={['/' ]}
      initialIndex={1}
    >
      <Navbar/>
    </MemoryRouter>
  )
  const tree = renderer.create(wrapper).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});

it('renders without crashing', () => {
  shallow(<Navbar />);
});
```

And here is the error I'm getting:

```
Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop.
```

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you're suing `mount` instead of `shallow`?

I'm sort of a newbie... seriously asking...

I was running into this same problem with `shallow` and the solution I came up with...

(if using `shallow` is justifiable... )

try this:

```
 `
    <div key={1}> // this is the dude here
        <MemoryRouter>
             <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
    </div>`
```

I'm assuming MemoryWrapper ignores unfamiliar props.

I would like to know if this is a decent solution or if there's something else we're (I'm) missing.

interesting console play... it looks like `mount` hits some lifecycles more than once, so the key wouldn't be unique after round 1, but not sure how you would pass that.

App.js

```
`class App extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('componentWillMount');
}
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
}
 componentWillReceiveProps() {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps');
}
 shouldComponentUpdate() {
    console.log('shouldComponentUpdate');
    return true;
}
 componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log('componentWillUpdate');
}
 componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('componentDidUpdate');
}
 componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='App-main'>
        <Route path='/' component={Header}/>
        <Route path='/' component={About} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}`
```

App.test.js w/ `mount`

`it('renders App without crashing', () => {
  const appWrapper =
    mount(
      <div key={1}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </div>
  );`

console.logs from app.js with `MOUNT`

```
`console.log src/App.js:17
    componentWillMount

  console.log src/App.js:20
    componentDidMount

  console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:33
    Warning: Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key" prop. See https://some-dumb-shit.org for more information.

  console.log src/App.js:17
    componentWillMount

  console.log src/App.js:20
    componentDidMount

  console.log src/App.js:36
    componentWillUnmount`
```

App.test.js w/ `SHALLOW`

`it('renders App without crashing', () => {
  const appWrapper =
    shallow(
      <div key={1}>
        <MemoryRouter>
          <App />
        </MemoryRouter>
      </div>
  );`

console.logs from app.js with `SHALLOW`

```
`console.log src/App.js:17
    componentWillMount

  console.log src/App.js:20
    componentDidMount

  console.log src/App.js:36
    componentWillUnmount`
```

no error. I'm not sure if my answer is correct in that maybe you were using mount when you should have used shallow? But, there's got to be some purpose for mount, and some way to rid the error.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the initial entries on a `MemoryRouter` it should be generating an unique key for each entry. Based on your error message it could even be a problem with how your NavBar is implemented.

But, if its not, you can set a custom `key` in the `initialEntries` array like shown [here](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/5579).

So you would end up with your MemoryRouter like this:

```
<MemoryRouter  
  initialEntries={[ { pathname: '/', key: 'testKey' } ]}
  initialIndex={1}
>
  <Navbar/>
</MemoryRouter>
```

And this will provide the same key in all tests. (I tested with react-router-dom v5.1.2)